# Android MVVM Dagger 2 - ViewModelFactory Injection

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, dagger-2

I am trying to perform viewmodel injection with dagger 2 in Android Kotlin project. So far my project looks like this. I have AppComponent looking like this

```
    @AppScope
@Component(modules = [
    ViewModelModule::class,
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,


 AppModule::class,
    BuildersModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application : App) : Builder
        fun build() : AppComponent
    }

   fun inject(app: App)    

}
```

My appModule:

```
@Module class AppModule
```

I created also Builders module for providing my Views:

```
@Module
abstract class BuildersModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun providesMainActivity() : MainActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector()
    abstract fun providesModeMenuActivity(): ModeMenuActivity

}
```

My view model facotory is taken from example on [github project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample)

```
@AppScope
class ViewModelFactory
@Inject constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?:
        creators.asIterable().firstOrNull { modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key) }?.value
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass)

        return try {
            creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }
}
```

I bound factory in my ViewModelModule like this:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ModeMenuViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindModeMenuViewModel(modeMenuViewModel: ModeMenuViewModel): ModeMenuViewModel

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindsViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

}
```

Now everything builds until I add ViewModelFacotory injection in one of activities like this:

```
class ModeMenuActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var vmFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        AndroidInjection.inject(this)

       val binding: ActivityModeMenuBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_mode_menu)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, vmFactory).get(ModeMenuViewModel::class.java)
       binding.ViewModel = viewModel

    }


}
```

When I build code afret adding @Inject I get following error:

```
C:\Users\Maciej\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidMVVM\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\maciej\androidmvvm\di\AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
          com.example.maciej.androidmvvm.ViewModelModule.ViewModelFactory.<init>(creators)
      com.example.maciej.androidmvvm.ViewModelModule.ViewModelFactory is injected at
          com.example.maciej.androidmvvm.ViewModelModule.ViewModelModule.bindsViewModelFactory(factory)
      android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
          com.example.maciej.androidmvvm.ui.common.ModeMenu.ModeMenuActivity.vmFactory
      com.example.maciej.androidmvvm.ui.common.ModeMenu.ModeMenuActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
  component path: com.example.maciej.androidmvvm.di.AppComponent ? com.example.maciej.androidmvvm.di.BuildersModule_ProvidesModeMenuActivity.
```

So far I couldn't find anything at forums so I would be thankfull if you could show my what am I doing wrong. Also I noticed that when I try to attach view model to my binding object in Activity I get type missmatch (it shows incomplete package name as required type)

Comment: I've only had a few minutes to look at this, but I think that `@ViewModelKey` is mapping your ViewModel to a KClass, not a Java Class

Comment: Can you add code of `ModeMenuViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is a no op since you're returning the same type you're passing as argument, so change return type like this

Before:

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(ModeMenuViewModel::class)
abstract fun bindModeMenuViewModel(modeMenuViewModel: ModeMenuViewModel): ModeMenuViewModel
```

After:

```
Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(ModeMenuViewModel::class)
abstract fun bindModeMenuViewModel(modeMenuViewModel: ModeMenuViewModel): ViewModel
```

Comment: Just to be clear, it isn't exactly a NOOP, since it binds the view model into the map.  It doesn't provide enough info, though, for Dagger to connect the dots.  Alternatively, you could do this:  ``` @Binds
    abstract fun bindsModeMenuViewModel(modeMenuViewModel: ModeMenuViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ModeMenuViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindModeMenuViewModelMap(modeMenuViewModel: ViewModel): ViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution. Dagger had problems with my packages names started from big letters. When I changed all packages names to camel case everything started to work.